# Angular 8: how can we detect re-rendering of a component (as event)

Tags: angular, components

I need something as event to catch a re-rendering of a component in Angular 8

Comment: Can you please add more details ?

Comment: I send a request via HttpClient. And when I get a response the state is updated and the component is re-rendered. I need to catch this moment of re-rendering

Comment: Please check the answer and added some example of code

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are changing anything on UI/state then `ngOnChanges` is going to call.

`ngOnChanges()` `(OnChanges)` is called when a value bound to input has changed so you can run custom code when an input has changed.

`ngDoCheck()` `(DoCheck)` is called when change detection runs so you can implement your custom change detection action.

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
     console.log('on change', changes)
  }
```

If you are handling HTTP response and you want to observe it then use `BehaviorSubject`.

Please check the following example,

**Service to call API - TestService**

```
        private test = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

        getTest() {
            // ...
            return this.http.get(_url, options)
                .map(response => {
                    const responseAsObject = response.json();
                    this.test.next(responseAsObject); // change the value!
                });
        }
```

**In your component**

```
        export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
            private testObj : any;

            constructor(
              private testService: TestService,
            ) {}

            ngOnInit() {
                this.testService.getTest
                    .subscribe(test => {
                        // here is the test object from the service, you can do whatever you want with it
                        // it fires when you get the updated response
                });  
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help you.